# Windows Sandbox: enable optional features within sandbox

Tags: windows, iis, windows-sandbox

I'm busy writing a powershell script that sets up IIS. I'm using windows Sandbox to test the script but it does not seem to have the "OptionalFeatures.exe" so I cannot enable IIS either manually or via command.

Is there a way to set this up in the sandbox?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Since important services were disabled on Windows Sandbox, it is not likely that a feature like IIS is even supported there. You should use a full virtual machine to test your script instead.